# Athena Node.js AWS SDK - Any request throws InvalidRequestException

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm using Node 10.x LTS and AWS + Serverless, I've setup a DB using S3 and Athena.

I'm tring to run a query using the official `aws-sdk/Athena`. **Everything works fine locally**, however once the lambda is deployed to AWS any query I try to run returns `InvalidRequestException`.

Here's my code:

```
'use strict'

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const athena = new AWS.Athena({ athena: '2017-05-18' })
const sleep = require('util').promisify(setTimeout)
const parseAthenaResponse = require('../../utils/parseAthenaResponse')

const getQueryResults = async QueryExecutionId => {
  await sleep(5000)
  const { QueryExecution } = await athena
    .getQueryExecution({ QueryExecutionId })
    .promise()

  if (
    QueryExecution.Status.State !== 'SUCCEEDED' &&
    QueryExecution.Status.State !== 'FAILED' &&
    QueryExecution.Status.State !== 'CANCELLED'
  ) {
    console.log(`Not ready yet: ${JSON.stringify(QueryExecution, null, 2)}`)
    return getQueryResults(QueryExecutionId)
  }

  console.info(`(${QueryExecutionId}) Results ready, download started`)
  const data = await athena.getQueryResults({ QueryExecutionId }).promise()
  return data.ResultSet.Rows
}

const getDataFromAthena = async () => {
  try {
    var QueryString = `
      SELECT * FROM my_table
    `

    const params = {
      QueryString,
      QueryExecutionContext: {
        Database: 'test'
      },
      ResultConfiguration: {
        OutputLocation: `s3://${process.env.S3_BUCKET}/exports`
      }
    }

    var { QueryExecutionId } = await athena
      .startQueryExecution(params)
      .promise()

    console.info(`(${QueryExecutionId}) Getting query results...`)
    const data = await getQueryResults(QueryExecutionId)
    return parseAthenaResponse(data)
  } catch (err) {
    // InvalidRequestException error is caught here
    throw err
  }
}

module.exports = getDataFromAthena
```

I believe it's not a permission issue since, for testing purposes, I'm granting the lambda access to everything:

```
iamRoleStatements:
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action: "s3:*"
    Resource: "*"
  - Effect: "Allow"
    Action: "athena:*"
    Resource: "*"
```

Unfortunately the error is very generic and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which call is throwing the exception? Is it `startQueryExecution`, `getQueryExecution`, or `athena.getQueryResults`?

Comment: @Theo I run some tests and I found out that yes, getQueryResults is the method throwing the error but the issue is in the startQueryExecution method. If I run startQueryExecution locally and then getQueryResults on AWS, everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InvalidRequestException` could mean a lot of different things, and it's dependent on which call that threw it. The most common reason for `InvalidRequestException` is that the call is malformed somehow, a missing required parameter, the value of a parameter being invalid, etc.

If it's the `getQueryResults` call that throws it, I think it could also could mean that the query results are not available. It looks like you're correctly waiting for the query to finish before calling `getQueryResults`, but you also call it for failed, and cancelled queries, that could be the issue. You should not call `getQueryResults` unless the state is `SUCCEEDED`.

Also note you need [permissions to the Glue catalog](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/fine-grained-access-to-glue-resources.html) to run a query, that could be an issue. On the other hand you should have gotten `AccessDenied` errors in that case.

Comment: I run some tests and I found out that yes, `getQueryResults` is the method throwing the error but the issue is in the `startQueryExecution` method. 
If I run `startQueryExecution` locally and then `getQueryResults` on AWS, everything works fine.

Comment: I added `glue:*` to the permissions and it worked! Thanks for the help :)